# C# フォームの背景を右下に表示させたい

Tags: c#, form

お世話になります。

C#にて、フォームを生成して、BackgroundImageを設定した後、BackgroundImageLayoutをNoneに
すれば、設定した画像は左上に表示されますが、これを右下に表示されることはできますでしょうか。もちろん、フォームの拡大・縮小に合わせて配置されるものとします。また、元の画像自体には一切手を加えないものとします。

自分で考えた方法ですが、フォームの起動時、及びサイズ変更時にフォーム全体のサイズを図り、それに対するクライアント領域と同じサイズのイメージを生成し、そのイメージの右下に描画されるように背景の画像を描画した後、そのイメージをフォームの背景として設定する…などの方法があると
思いましたが、そもそももっと簡単に設定だけで行うことはできますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BackgroundImageLayout`プロパティは[ImageLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelayout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)のみ設定可能ですので、「簡単に設定だけで」右下に表示することはできないと認識しています。

本家SOの[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707562/position-of-backgroundimage-in-windows-form)では`OnPaintBackground`イベントで[再描画](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3707769)するコード例が紹介されています。

Comment: ありがとうございます。設定だけではできないというのが解れば十分です。Accessのフォームなどでは設定でできるのだから、あってもおかしくないと思ったのですが、少し残念ですが仕方ありません。